# XcodeでAVFoundationを使いBGMを切り替える方法を教えてください

Tags: swift

現在、おみくじのサンプルアプリで勉強をしています。
サンプルコードを参考にBGMの再生はできたのですが、BGMの切り替え方法がわかりません。
画面推移を使わず、同一画面のままBGMを切り替えたいです。

どんなコードをどの部分に入れればBGMが切り替え出来ますか？

わかる方いましたら、ご教授よろしくおねがします。
使用している環境はXcode7 swift2.0です。

ーーGameViewController　BGM１を再生ーー

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation     //AVFoundationフレームワークをインポートする。

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var player:AVAudioPlayer?       //BGM を制御するための変数
    var soundManager = SEManager()  //SEManager でインスタンス化した変数
    //BGM再生メソッド
    func play(soundName:String){
        //サウンドファイルを読み込む
        let soundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(soundName)
        //読み込んだファイルにパスを付ける
        let url:NSURL? = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundPath)
        do {
            //↓playerに読み込んだmp3ファイルへのパスを設定する
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:url!)
        } catch _ {
            player = nil
        }
        player?.numberOfLoops = -1      //BGMを無限にループさせる
        player?.prepareToPlay()         //音声を即時再生させる。
        player?.play()                  //音を再生する
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //bgm
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //playメソッドの呼び出し。引数はファイル名。
        play("bgm1.mp3")


        let scene = GameScene(size:CGSize(width: 750, height: 1334))
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFit
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

・・・・・GameScene.swift

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class GameScene: SKScene {
    // イラスト用スプライトを用意する
    let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "omikuji.png")
    // ボタン用スプライトを用意する
    let btnSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button.png")
    // おみくじ結果用ラベルを用意する
    let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Verdana-bold")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {



        // 背景色をつける
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        // イラストを表示する
        mySprite.position = CGPoint(x: 375, y: 900)
        addChild(mySprite)
        // ボタンを表示する
        btnSprite.position = CGPoint(x:375, y:200)
        self.addChild(btnSprite)
        // おみくじ結果用ラベルを表示する
        myLabel.text = "???"
        myLabel.fontSize = 65
        myLabel.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:375, y:500)
        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }
    // タッチしたときの処理
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            // タッチされた位置にあるものを調べて
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let touchNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
            // もし、ボタンなら
            if touchNode == btnSprite {

                //効果音がなった時、BGMは停止しない


                // 効果音データの作成.
                let mySoundAction: SKAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("hit.wav", waitForCompletion: true)
                // 再生アクション.
                self.runAction(mySoundAction);

                // ???と表示してから、おみくじを振る
                myLabel.text = "???"
                shakeOmikuji()
            }
        }
    }
    // おみくじを振る処理
    func shakeOmikuji() {

        //BGMサンプル１再生停止
        //ここでBGMをサンプル２に切り替えたい


        // 【おみくじを振るアクションをつける】
        // おみくじを少し右に傾けるアクション
        let action1 = SKAction.rotateToAngle(-0.3, duration: 0.2)
        // おみくじを少し左に傾けるアクション
        let action2 = SKAction.rotateToAngle( 0.3, duration: 0.2)
        // おみくじをひっくり返すアクション
        let action3 = SKAction.rotateToAngle( 3.14, duration: 0.2)
        // action1,action2,action3を指定した順番に行う
        let actionS = SKAction.sequence(
            [action1, action2, action1, action2, action1, action3])

        // おみくじに「左右に振ってひっくり返すアクション」をつけて、最後にkekkaを実行する
        mySprite.runAction(actionS, completion: showOmikuji)
    }
    // 結果を表示する処理
    func showOmikuji() {
        var omikuji = ["大吉","中吉","吉","凶"]
        let r = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))
        myLabel.text = omikuji[r]
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    }
}
```

Comment: とりあえず、`GameViewController`で読み込んでいる`var player:AVAudioPlayer?`を、`GameScene`に移動しましょう。

Comment: 移動しました。bgm1はエラーなく流れています。bgm2はまだ設定できていません。

Answer (score 1):

どんなきっかけでBGMの変更がしたいですか？
それにより追加するコードが変わります。
例えば、ボタンのタップでBGMが変更される。などです。
単純に音楽を変えたい場合は、AVAudioPlayerをstop()して、再度パス指定をしてprepareToPlay()をすれば変更できます。

Comment: 単純に音楽をBGM1からBGM２に切り替えたいです。再度パス指定をしたいのですが、そのコードをどこにどんな形でかけばいいのでしょうか？　AVFoundationの部分は本を読んで打っているので、いまいち使いこなせておらず、すみません。希望の形としては、GameScene.swift内でplay("bgm2.mp3")とコードを打ったらbgm2.mp3が流れるようにしたいのです。

Comment: そしたらまず、GameViewControllerのvar player:AVAudioPlayer?〜func play(...){〜}の終わりまでを切り取って、GameScene.swiftのlet myLabelの次の行に貼り付けましょう。次にGameViewControllerのviewDidLoadのplay("bgm1.mp3")を切り取って、GameScene.swiftのdidMoveToViewに貼り付けましょう。そうするとbgm1は流れますか？

Comment: 貼り付けましたところ、無事、bgm1は流れました。続いてbgm2に切り替えたいのですが、どのようなコードを追加すればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、play("bgm1.mp3")をplay("bgm2.mp3")にしたら切り替えができました。ただ、stop命令のコードがどう書くのかわからず、BGMが止められない状態です。BGMを止める命令、play(stop)？　の書き方を教えてください。

Comment: player?.stop()ですね。   [こちら](https://akira-watson.com/iphone/avaudioplayer.html)が参考になります。

Answer (score 0):

以下、一本指タップで、BGMが変わり、二本指（以上）タップで、BGM再生を止めたり再開するプログラムです。

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var southernURL: NSURL!
    private var happyURL: NSURL!
    var currentBGM: AVAudioPlayer!

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)

        let bndl = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        southernURL = bndl.URLForResource("southern", withExtension: "m4a")
        happyURL = bndl.URLForResource("happy", withExtension: "m4a")

        currentBGM = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: southernURL, error: nil)
        currentBGM.numberOfLoops = -1
        currentBGM.play()
    }

    override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
        super.willMoveFromView(view)

        if currentBGM.playing == true {
            currentBGM.stop()
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if touches.count < 2 { // 一本指タップなら
            changeBGM()
        } else { // 二本指以上なら
            pauseBGM()
        }
    }

    func changeBGM() {
        if currentBGM.playing {
            currentBGM.stop()
            if currentBGM.url == southernURL {
                currentBGM = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: happyURL, error: nil)
            } else {
                currentBGM = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: southernURL, error: nil)
            }
            currentBGM.numberOfLoops = -1
            currentBGM.play()
        }
    }

    func pauseBGM() {
        if currentBGM.playing {
            currentBGM.pause() // pause()なら、サウンドファイルとのつながりが切れない。そして再開時、停止したところから始まる。
        } else {
            currentBGM.play()
        }
    }

}
```

確実にnilにならないことが保証されているケースでは、インスタンス変数をOptional（?）ではなく、Inplicitly Unwrapped Optional（!）にすることができます。なお、「確実にnilにならない保証」をするのは、プログラマ自身です。

`NSBundle`の`URLForResource()`などは、リソースファイルの取得に失敗すると、`nil`を返します。なので、swift2.0の例外処理を使う必要はありません。今回は、「プログラマの責任」で、まちがいなくサウンドファイルがある前提で、Inplicitly Unwrapped Optional（!）としましたが、サウンドファイル取得を失敗した時のケースを考慮するなら、Optional Binding等を使って、変数の内容が`nil`かそうでないかで条件分岐してください。

再生開始時のタイムラグ（遅延）を気にしなければ、`prepareToPlay()`メソッドは呼ぶ必要はありません。